# xml parsing with beautifulsoup4, namespaces issue

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup, docx

While parsing .docx file contents in form of xml (word/document.xml) with beautifulsoup4 (with lxml installed, as required) I encountered one problem. This part from xml:

```
    ...
    <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
        <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
            <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
    ...
```

becomes this:

```
    ...
    <graphic>
        <graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
            <pic>
    ...
```

Even when I just parse file and save it, without any modifications. Like this:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filepath_in), 'xml')
    with open(filepath_out, "w+") as fd:
        fd.write(str(soup))
```

Or parse xml from python console.

For me it looks like namespaces, declared like this, not in root document node, get eaten by parser.

Is this a bug, or feature? And is there a way to preserve these while parsing with beautifulesoup4? Or do I need to switch to something else for that?

**UPDATE 1:** if with some regex and text replacement I add these namespace declarations to the root `document` node, then beautifulsoup parses it just fine. But I'm still interested if this can be solved without modification of xml before parsing.

**UPDATE 2:** after playing with beutifulsoup a bit, I figured out that namespace declarations are parsed only in first occurrence. Means that if tag declares namespace, then if its children have namespace declarations, they will not be parsed. Below is code example with output to illustrate that.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
xmls = []
xmls.append("""<name1:tag xmlns:name1="namespace1" xmlns:name2="namespace2">
<name2:intag>
text
</name2:intag>
</name1:tag>
""")
xmls.append("""<tag>
<name2:intag xmlns:name2="namespace2">
text
</name2:intag>
</tag>
""")
xmls.append("""<name1:tag xmlns:name1="namespace1">
<name2:intag xmlns:name2="namespace2">
text
</name2:intag>
</name1:tag>
""")
for i, xml in enumerate(xmls):
    print "============== xml {} ==============".format(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")
    print soup
```

Will produce output:

```
============== xml 0 ==============
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<name1:tag xmlns:name1="namespace1" xmlns:name2="namespace2">
<name2:intag>
text
</name2:intag>
</name1:tag>
============== xml 1 ==============
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tag>
<name2:intag xmlns:name2="namespace2">
text
</name2:intag>
</tag>
============== xml 2 ==============
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<name1:tag xmlns:name1="namespace1">
<intag>
text
</intag>
</name1:tag>
```

See, how first two xmls are parsed correctly, while second declaration in third one gets eaten.

Actually this problem does not involve docx anymore. And my question is rounded to such: is this behavior hardcoded in beautifulsoup4, and if not, then how can I change it?

Comment: I've had success with passing 'lxml' to the soup constructor instead of 'xml'. Not always though...

Comment: `lxml` updated?

Comment: Any reason not opting to use other dedicated xml-specific parsing built-in library like ElementTree?

Answer (score 0):

From the W3C recommendation:

> The Prefix provides the namespace prefix part of the qualified name, and **MUST** be associated with a namespace URI reference in a namespace declaration.

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames

So I think it is the expected behaviour: discard the namespaces not declared to gracefully allow some parsing on documents that not respect the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filepath_in), 'xml')
```

to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filepath_in), 'lxml')
```

or

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filepath_in), 'html.parser')
```